# VBScript onTimeout then function

Tags: vbscript, timeout

I have a VBScript I am working on that uses another object.

Sometimes that Object will get stuck. My VBScript code will hang on that line until it's "done". When it times out, I want to send the .Close command to the Object before the VBScript closes.

How can I tell when my VBScript times out?

I know that I can put WScript.Timeout = 60

Maybe something like..

```
WScript.Timeout = 5
do while true

loop

sub WScript_timeout()
    msgbox("OK")
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the `Timeout` property you instruct the interpreter to automatically terminate the script when the timer expires. This is the same as running the interpreter with the option `//T:xx` and can't be caught/handled from within the script. What you want requires the ability to run code asynchronously, and VBScript doesn't really support that.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer (to the question "How can I tell when my **VBScript** times out?") is that you *can't*. In common with almost all scripts, if VBScript stops running (because it's timed-out) the running thread *ceases* to run, so it can't report its status.

But there is a solution. However, it requires some cunning.

If you run a **batch script** instead, wherever you use that script to launch a *new* batch script (e.g. **batch_1.bat** includes this line: **CALL batch_2.bat**), the 2nd script will run, but the 1st script will wait.

Processing of the 1st script sits and waits (at the CALL) until script 2 stops running: at that point, control is returned to script 1, which continues with any code following the CALL, code which might be used to report the fact that script 2 has ended -

```
CALL batch_2.bat
ECHO The batch_2.bat script has stopped running && cmd /k
```

There are ways of launching batch_2.bat *without* causing batch_1.bat to pause until the 2nd script has finished, but they are not relevent here.

Theoretically, a batch script doesn't support parallel processing. VBScript certainly doesn't either. But the foregoing technique shows one method whereby parallel processing can be achieved, after a fashion, in a batch script -- which makes it *one-up* on vbScript!

.

One way to be certain that vbScript will time out, if the script hangs, so that the script must *either* complete successfully *or* fail (so you are never left with a frozen script due to it "hanging"), is to use a **WScript** function in your .vbs file and set the **Windows Script Host** settings to time out after (say) 30 seconds -

**A**. Open the "Windows Script Host Settings" dialog box:

1. Go to: Start > Run
2. In the "Open" box, type: WSCRIPT
3. Click "OK".

**B**. Set a timeout, to occur whenever WSH runs:

1. Select the option: "Stop script after specified
   number of seconds".
2. In the "seconds" box, type the time limit to be
   applied to all scripts (default is 10 seconds).

.

Here's a function to find and show what the current **WSH/WScript timeout setting** is (and if it shows that this setting hasn't been set yet, set it) -

```
WScript.Echo("WSH timeout: " + WScript.Timeout);
```

.

The option `//T:xx` can't be used, because it's a **CScript** function, which doesn't work in WScript, so can't be used in a .vbs vbScript file.

.